# UML Class-Diagramm local variables

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Is it necessary to declare all used variables in an Java UML Class-Diagram?

Because if it is, every local- or loop-variable is shown, so the diagram grows huge.

My first thought was to only show the global variables.

Can anybody tell me what is right?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A class diagram shows classes with their attributes and methods. It doesn't show the body of the methods, which is where local variables are declared. It's never necessary to do anything in a diagram. A diagram is a documentation tool, allowing you to document the design of your code. The goal is to make things as understandable as possible. Not to blindly follow rules.

Comment: That makes sense. I was not sure, because I thought it is important to show all variables for understandig the code.
Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Class-Diagram shows the methods and variables that are defined in the class context. It does not show "local" variables that are defined in a method's context.

### Example

**Java code:**

```
class Square
{
    private double width;
    private double height;
    
    public Square()
    {
        width = 6.0;
        height = 7.0;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        double a; // local variable -- NOT shown in the class diagram
        a = width * height;
        return a;
    }
}
```

**Class diagram:**

The variable `a` is defined in the `getArea()` method's context and is therefore not shown in the class diagram:

```
+--------------------+
|       Square       |
+--------------------+
| -width:double      |
| -height:double     |
+--------------------+
| +Square()          |
| +getArea():double  |
+--------------------+
```

**Note:** A class diagram does not necessarily has to show *all* variables and methods. You could hide the private members or the constructor, for example, if you think that its not relevant for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the target reader group. You can decide to show

- just the class name
- only public methods/properties
- also private m/o
- and the same for package/protected scope

So the answer is: no it is not necessary. But you are allowed to do so if you need it.